# TikZ: curved arrows with symbol between, problem with centering and tilting

Tags: arrows, tikz-cd

I'm trying to diagram a mathematical concept, but for some reason the symbol is tilted and the labels are not centered. I've tried tweaking parameters such as pos, but there must be a better way in general:

```
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
\Gph\arrow[r,bend left,"F_C",""{name=A, below}] & \Cat\arrow[l,bend left,"U_G",""{name=B,above}] \arrow[from=A, to=B, symbol=\dashv] \arrow[r,bend left,"F_P",""{name=C, below}] & \Pos \arrow[l,bend left,"U_C",""{name=D,above}] \arrow[r,bend left,"U_S",""{name=E, below}] \arrow[from=C, to=D, symbol=\dashv] & \Set \arrow[l,bend left,"F_P",""{name=F,above}] \arrow[from=F, to=E, symbol=\dashv]
\end{tikzcd}
\]
```

[image: result]

Please let me know a more systematic way to make these diagrams; thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please provide an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). What do the commands `\Gph`, `\Cat` and so on do?

Comment: Thanks! I thought my question did provide an MWE. The commands just print the corresponding names in non-math font.

Answer (score 8):

I just reworked your entry as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\def\ac{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\dashv$}} %rotate dash anti-cw
\def\cw{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{$\dashv$}} %rotate dash cw
%\tikzset{adj/.style={pos=0.545,outer sep=3pt}} %adjust label position along path

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=small]
    Gph \arrow[bend left,below]{rr}{F_C}
    & \cw &
    \arrow[bend left,above]{ll}{U_G} Cat \arrow[bend left,below]{rr}{F_P}
    %\arrow[bend left,above, adj]{ll}{U_G} Cat \arrow[bend left,below]{rr}{F_P}
    & \dashv &
    \arrow[bend left,above]{ll}{U_C} Pos \arrow[bend left,below]{rr}{U_S}
    & \ac &
    Set \arrow[bend left,above]{ll}{F_P}
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I have also added code to rotate the \dashv symbol. Showing the normal \dashv and the clockwise and anticlockwise rotations.

Added a command (commented out) for adjusting the position of a label along the arrow, and its distance from the line. You can play around with values until you get a result you like. Below, the first picture shows the resulting misplaced label with 'column sep = tiny'.

[image]

The subsequent picture using the commented out commands adjust the label position to be aligned vertically with the other label, and showing that you can push the label further from the line by 3pt.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much; works perfectly. This will probably help another category theorist in the future.

Comment: Just a note, if you set 'column sep = tiny' the U_G label will not line up, and will appear as in your initial figure.

Answer (score 2):

A different approch to the original code.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\newcommand{\pdashv}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{$\dashv$}}
\newcommand{\vdashv}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{0}{$\dashv$}}
\newcommand{\sdashv}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\dashv$}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
Gph \arrow[rr, "F_C", bend left] & \pdashv & Cat 
\arrow[ll, "U_G", bend left] 
\arrow[rr, "F_P", bend left] & \vdashv & Pos \arrow[ll, "U_C", bend left] 
\arrow[rr, "U_S", bend left] & \sdashv & Set \arrow[ll, "F_P", bend left]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```