# Drawing arcs under letters

Tags: tikz-styles, tikz-cd

I have been trying to draw something like [image]

Can anyone help me with the code? I have no idea how to do this. Your help would be appreciated.

Edit: Based on comments, I got the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{pstricks} 
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{pst-grad} % For gradients
\usepackage{pst-plot} % For axes
\usepackage[space]{grffile} % For spaces in paths
\usepackage{etoolbox} % For spaces in paths
\makeatletter % For spaces in paths
\patchcmd\Gread@eps{\@inputcheck#1 }{\@inputcheck"#1"\relax}{}{}
\makeatother 
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\def\ac{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\dashv$}} %rotate dash anti-cw
\def\cw{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{$\dashv$}} %rotate dash cw
%\tikzset{adj/.style={pos=0.545,outer sep=3pt}} %adjust label position along path

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=small]
    q 
& &
    \arrow[bend left,above]{ll}{a} -q 
    %\arrow[bend left,above, adj]{ll}{U_G} Cat \arrow[bend left,below]{rr}{F_P}
& &
  q 
& &
    q^2 
    & & 
    -q^2\arrow[bend left,above]{ll}{b}
    & &
    q^2
    & &
    -q^2\arrow[bend left,above]{ll}{b}
    & & 
    -q
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

which gives [image]

But I am not able to draw the big underline.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/586711/47927

Comment: There's [tikz pgf - Draw arrows to show multiplication pattern (distributive property) - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168972/draw-arrows-to-show-multiplication-pattern-distributive-property) — and also [TikZ: curved arrows with symbol between, problem with centering and tilting - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/426284/tikz-curved-arrows-with-symbol-between-problem-with-centering-and-tilting) but that one is quite different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add another arrow in a similar fashion you have added the ones.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\def\ac{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\dashv$}} %rotate dash anti-cw
\def\cw{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{$\dashv$}} %rotate dash cw
%\tikzset{adj/.style={pos=0.545,outer sep=3pt}} %adjust label position along path

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=small]
    q 
& &
    \arrow[bend left,above]{ll}{a} -q 
    %\arrow[bend left,above, adj]{ll}{U_G} Cat \arrow[bend left,below]{rr}{F_P}
& &
   q  
& &
    q^2 
    & & 
    -q^2\arrow[bend left,above]{ll}{b}
    & &
    q^2
    & &
    -q^2\arrow[bend left,above]{ll}{b}
    & & 
    \arrow[bend left,above]{llllllllll}{b} % <--- addition
    -q\\
    &&  &&&&&\\
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you don't want an arrowhead, use the option `dash` in the `arrow` command like this `\arrow[dash, bend left]...`.